# Does this sum converge uniformly?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, harmonic-analysis

Let $f:S^1\to\mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function and define
$$f_n(e^{i\theta})=\sum_{k=-n}^n\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(e^{it})e^{ik(\theta-t)}dt.$$
Then must $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $S^1$? I believe the answer is no because
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty e^{ik(\theta-t)}=\frac{1}{1-e^{i(\theta-t)}}+\frac{1}{1-e^{-i(\theta-t)}}-1$$
which has a pole at $t=\theta$. However, I can't find an explicit counterexample. Does anyone know of one?

Comment: Need not even converge pointwise. Have you studied Fourier series?

Comment: @geetha290krm I am studying some harmonic analysis now which is how this question came up. What is an example for which it does not converge pointwise?

Comment: @Gonçalo Good point, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: There is the famous Fejer's example. See p. 154 of Fourier Series by R E Edwards.

Comment: @geetha290krm I have the book open and do not see the example you are referring to. This is the page with exercises for chapter 9. Are you referring to some exercise?

Comment: You can look for Fejer's example in the index.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks. I found it as example 10.3.1 on page 161 of my copy of the book.